# Rolling total in SQL that Resets to 0 when going above 90

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, recursive-query

First time post. Learning SQL over the past 6 months so help is appreciated. I have data structured as below:

```
DECLARE @tmp4 as TABLE (
    AccountNumber int,
    Date            date,
    DateRank        int
)

INSERT INTO @tmp4
VALUES (001, '11/13/2018' , 1)
, (002, '12/19/2018', 2)
, (003, '1/23/2019' , 3)
, (004, '2/5/2019' , 4)
, (005, '3/10/2019' , 5)
, (006, '3/20/2019' , 6)
, (007, '4/8/2019' , 7)
, (008, '5/20/2019' , 8)
```

What I need to do with this data is calculate a rolling total that resets to 0 once a threshold of 90 days is reached. I have used the DateDiff function to calculate the DateDiffs between consecutive dates and have tried multiple things using LAG and other window functions but can't make it reset. The goal is to find "index visits" which can only occur once every 90 days. So my plan is to have a field that reads 0 on the first visit and resets to 0 for the next stay after 90 days is up from the first visit then only pull visits with a value of 0.

One solution I tried was correct for most sets but did not return the right values for the above set (rows 4 and 8 should start over as "index visits").
The results I would expect for this query would be:

```
Account   Date         DateRank   RollingTotal

001     |'11/13/2018' | 1        | 0
002     |'12/19/2018' | 2        | 35
003     |'1/23/2019'  | 3        | 71
004     |'2/5/2019'   | 4        | 84
005     |'3/10/2019'  | 5        | 0  (not 117)
006     |'3/20/2019'  | 6        | 10 
007     |'4/8/2019'   | 7        | 29
008     |'5/20/2019'  | 8        | 71
```

Thanks for any help.

Here's the code I tried:

```
DECLARE @tmp2 as TABLE
(EmrNumber      varchar(255)
, AdmitDateTime datetime
, DateRank      int
, LagDateDiff   int
, RunningTotal  int
)

INSERT INTO @tmp2

SELECT tmp1.EmrNumber
        , tmp1.AdmitDateTime
        , tmp1.DateRank
--, LAG(tmp1.AdmitDateTime) OVER(PARTITION BY tmp1.EmrNumber ORDER BY tmp1.DateRank) as NextAdmitDate
, -DATEDIFF(DAY, tmp1.AdmitDateTime, LAG(tmp1.AdmitDateTime) OVER(PARTITION BY tmp1.EmrNumber ORDER BY tmp1.DateRank)) LagDateDiff
, IIF((SELECT SUM(sumt.total)
        FROM (
                SELECT -DATEDIFF(DAY, tmpsum.AdmitDateTime, LAG(tmpsum.AdmitDateTime) OVER(PARTITION BY tmpsum.EmrNumber ORDER BY tmpsum.DateRank)) total
                FROM @tmp tmpsum
                WHERE tmp1.EmrNumber = tmpsum.EmrNumber 
                AND tmpsum.AdmitDateTime <= tmp1.AdmitDateTime
        ) sumt) IS NULL, 0, (SELECT SUM(sumt.total)
        FROM (
                SELECT -DATEDIFF(DAY, tmpsum.AdmitDateTime, LAG(tmpsum.AdmitDateTime) OVER(PARTITION BY tmpsum.EmrNumber ORDER BY tmpsum.DateRank)) total
                FROM @tmp tmpsum
                WHERE tmp1.EmrNumber = tmpsum.EmrNumber 
                AND tmpsum.AdmitDateTime <= tmp1.AdmitDateTime
        ) sumt) ) as RunningTotal 

FROM @tmp tmp1 

SELECT *
, CASE WHEN LagDateDiff >90 THEN 0
    WHEN RunningTotal = 0 THEN 0
    ELSE LAG(LagDateDiff) OVER(PARTITION BY EmrNumber ORDER BY DateRank) + RunningTotal END AS RollingTotal
FROM @tmp2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a recursive query for this, because the running total has to be checked iteratively, row after row:

```
with cte as (
    select 
        Account, 
        Date, 
        DateRank, 
        0 RollingTotal
    from @tmp4
    where DateRank = 1
    union all
    select 
        t.Account, 
        t.Date,
        t.DateRank,
        case when RollingTotal + datediff(day, c.Date, t.Date) > 90
            then 0
            else RollingTotal  + datediff(day, c.Date, t.Date)
        end
    from cte c
    inner join @tmp4 t on t.DateRank = c.DateRank + 1
)
select * from cte
```

The anchor of the cte selects the first record (as indicated by `DateRank`. Then, the recursive part processes rows one by one, and resets the running count when it crosses 90.